# In GitHub Actions' service containers, how do I use images from a private registry that uses a self-signed certificate?

Tags: docker, github, ssl, github-actions

Inside my GitHub action job, I want to create service containers (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-containerized-services/about-service-containers#creating-service-containers) using images from a private registry (e.g. jfrog rather than Docker Hub). However the server uses a self signed certificate which leads to this error:

`Error response from daemon: Get "*registry url here*": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`.

Is there any way to get docker to be aware of a custom CA cert (such as through an environment variable) that works with how GitHub's containerized services are set up?

Putting the certificate in `/etc/docker/certs.d/` seems like a possible solution but I'm not sure if it can be done before the containers are pulled.

An example of what my action looks like:

```
name: Service container test
on: push

jobs:
  container-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      custom-image:
        image: jfrog.fakeprivateserver.org/custom-image
        ports:
          - 8010:8010

    steps:
      ...
```